# create a register dynamic dataframe as temptable in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to registerTemptables, from dynamic dataframes.

I am getting the output as a string., i am not sure if there is  a way to execute dataframe or convert a string to dataframe so that the temptable can be created.

Here are the steps to replicate this issue :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val contact_df = sc.makeRDD(1 to 5).map(i => (i, i * i)).toDF("value", "square")
val acct_df = sc.makeRDD(1 to 5).map(i => (i, i / i)).toDF("value", "devide")

val dataframeJoins = Array( 
  Row("x","","",""  ,"Y","",1,"contact_hotline_df","contact_df","acct_nbr","hotline_df","tm49_acct_nbr"),
  Row("x","","","","Y","",2,"contact_hotline_acct_df","acct_df","tm06_acct_nbr"  ,"contact_hotline_df","acct_nbr")
)

val dfJoinbroadcast = sc.broadcast(dataframeJoins)

val DFJoins1 = for ( row <- dfJoinbroadcast.value ) yield {  
  (row(8)+".registerTempTable(\""+row(8)+"\")" )
}

for (rows <- 0 until DFJoins1.size ){
  println(DFJoins1(rows) )
  DFJoins1(rows)
}
```

Here is the output of the above for loop :

```
contact_df.registerTempTable("contact_df")
acct_df.registerTempTable("acct_df")
```

I am not getting any error. But the table is not getting created.

When i say sqlContext.sql("select * from contact_df") i am getting an error that table is not created.

Is there a way to convert string to a dataframe and execute the dataframe to create temptable.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Sreehari

Comment: I am trying to understand your code, but it's very clumsy. I put there some indentation for start. Do not call the method with capital first letter.

Comment: your for loop basically prints the `contact_df.registerTempTable("contact_df")` but doesn't perform this code. Also I'd use the newer `createOrReplaceTempView()` method instead

Comment: `.map(i => (i, i / i))`  -> `.map((_, 1))` anyway, how is this related to your question?

Comment: @JiriKremser Thank you for the suggestion. I will use the newer createOrReplaceTempView going forward. From the code i have provided, I am expecting the for loop to create the temp table so that i can use the temp table in a select query there after. However, the temp table is not getting created as per the current logic in the code. Can you please let me know if there is a way to create the temp table in the for loop.

Comment: Of course it is possible to create it in the loop, but you are actually not creating it. You are just printing the code you want to execute. Analogy would be doing `println("1+1")` and wondering why it is printing `1+1` instead or `2` :]

Comment: You are concatenating the strings and want to evaluate the string as a code. But scala is not a scripting language and there is no equivalent of the eval function, that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your code concatenates the strings and prints the result, that's it. The `registerTempTable` method is not being called, that's why you cant use it in the SQL query. Try to do this:

```
// assuming we have this string to object mapping
val tableNameToDf = Map("contact_df" -> contact_df, "acct_df" -> acct_df)
```

you could restructure your for loop into something like:

```
val dfJoins = for (row <- dfJoinbroadcast.value) yield {
   val wannabeTable = row(8)
   tableNameToRdd(wannabeTable).createOrReplaceTempView(wannabeTable)
   wannabeTableName
}
```